# How to rename git remote branch name from upper case to lower case same name?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a git branch named `QA`, I want to rename it to lower case `qa` because I use the repository in gitlab pipeline and in gitlab pipeline the branch names are case sensitive.

I tried this post to rename the branch
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-rename-local-and-remote-git-branch/

It works when the new and old branch names are different but does not when we try to change the letters' casing.

So I am now stuck with this name.

Any idea if that is even achievable or not and how?

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? What happens when you do `git push origin qa`? Any error messages? Or the branch is pushed to remote `QA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this issue I suppose you use a case insensitive file system locally (branches are stored as files in .git directory) that means that `git checkout QA` and `git checkout qa` brings you to the same branch, even if you never created the `qa` branch.

You can also check it with `git branch` that list you only `QA` and not `qa`, but `git checkout qa` works and brings you to the same commit pointed out by `QA` (check with `git log` also).

That said you can't rename `QA` to `qa` locally because for git is the same branch and will say you `A branch named 'qa' already exists.`.

A solution could be create a backup branch, delete the original and rename the backup with the right name. Than push on the remote.

```
git branch qa_backup QA
git branch -d QA
git branch -m qa_backup qa
git push -u origin qa
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of commands:

```
# 1st, delete the remote branch
git push origin --delete QA

# Rename it locally
git branch -m QA qa

# And finally push
git push -u origin qa
```

PS. `-u` means `--set-upstream`.